# Nested object access in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to read Hello property inside settings objects..

```
{
    Hello: {
        hello: 'hello world'
    },

    responsive: [{

        World: 'world',

        settings: {
            read: console.log(Hello['hello']),

        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with the complete object literal? Currently it's just thrown away and `settings.read` is never called anyway.

Comment: The `.Hello` property is not part of the `.settings` object?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it: turn `read` into a function, and call it with the calling context set to the parent object:

```js
const obj = {
  Hello: {
    hello: 'hello world'
  },
  responsive: [{
    World: 'world',
    settings: {
      read: function() { console.log(this.Hello.hello); },
    }
  }]
};

obj.responsive[0].settings.read.call(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

There is no "Hello" property in the settings object.

The settings object has one property — `read` — and its value is the *return value* of calling `console.log(...)` (which is `undefined`).